# Filter Confluent Cloud "confluent-audit-log-events" topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-camel, confluent-cloud

How can I filter Confluent Cloud cluster audit log based on the environment while consuming from the topic: **confluent-audit-log-events** in spring boot application?

I'm using the camel route to consume from the audit topic.

```
public void configure() throws Exception {

        from("kafka:confluent-audit-log-events")
                .process(exchange -> {
                    log.info(this.KafkaDetails(exchange));
                });
    }

    private String KafkaDetails(Exchange exchange) {
        return exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
    }
```

Comment: It would be useful if you showed an example record from the topic that you'd like to filter on, but have you even tried `kafkaStream.stream("confluent-audit-log-events").filter()`?

Comment: @OneCricketeer, I'm using the Camel route as I posted in the above description!

Comment: Have you read this? https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/routes.html#Routes-Filters

Comment: @OneCricketeer Yeah, I read that one but I have no idea how can I filter from audit data using a header!

Comment: You dont need a header. You just use a `Predicate<String>` like `exchangeBody -> exchangeBody.contains("my-environment")`

Comment: Although, it is better if you parse the data into a Java class, then use Bean expressions on the filter - https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/languages/bean-language.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I have figured it out using the below filter before the process.

`.filter(body().convertToString().contains(kafkaClusterId))`